# How can I subtract tuples in a list?

Tags: python, math

Let's say I have a list with tuples in it.

Something like this:

```
listnum = [(18,12),(12,20)]
```

Is there a way I can subtract what is in the tuples and make listnum into:

```
listnum = [6,8]
```

As you can see It takes the biggest of the numbers in the tuple and subtracts it by the other.

Comment: iterate through it and it's a simple subtraction. What have you tried so far?

Comment: will there always be two, or could there be more? if there are more, do you want to subtract them pairwise, or reduce them all down to a single tuple?

Comment: @Austin please don't answer questions in comments

Comment: I tried

listnum = [abs(x) for x in listnum]

Comment: There will always be two and subtract them pairwise

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to subtract the two values that are inside each of the tuples, or do you want to subtract the first-values in the tuples then the second-values in the tuples? Your example does not distinguish between the two.

Comment: Subtract the two values that are inside each of the tuples.

Oops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension:-

```
>>> listnum = [(18,12),(12,20)]
>>> [(i-j) for i,j in listnum]
[6, -8]
>>> listnum = [(18,12),(12,20),(32,54),(2,43)]
>>> [(i-j) for i,j in listnum]
[6, -8, -22, -41]
```

And as you asked for `bigger number - smaller`; use `abs()` to calculate it.

```
>>> listnum = [(18,12),(12,20),(32,54),(2,43)]
>>> [abs(i-j) for i ,j in listnum]
[6, 8, 22, 41]
```

Comment: Needs to take the biggest of the numbers in the tuple and subtract it by the other.

Comment: In (12,20) it should be 20 - 12

Comment: @D.SuperFireball `[abs(i-j) for i,j in listnum]`    use this

Answer (score 3):

Just a list comprehension works fine.

```
listnum = [(18,12),(12,20)]
listnum = [x[0] - x[1] for x in listnum]
# [6, -8]
```

Edit: For subtracting the bigger number from the smaller one, you can do something like this instead.

```
listnum = [max(x[0],x[1]) - min(x[0], x[1]) for x in listnum]
# [6, 8]
```

Or you can be a bit more cheeky about it

```
listnum = [abs(x[0] - x[1]) for x in listnum]
# [6, 8]
```

Comment: Needs to take the biggest of the numbers in the tuple and subtract it by the other.

Comment: looks like a change from the original question. that should be easy enough to work with. @D.SuperFireball

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following, using the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function:

```
listnum = [(18,12),(12,20)]
listnum = list(map(lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1]),listnum))
print(listnum)
```

Result:

```
[6, 8]
```

Comment: Needs to take the biggest of the numbers in the tuple and subtract it by the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the list and append each answer to a new list, and output the list.

**Code**

```
y=[]
listnum = [(18,12),(12,20)]
for a,b in listnum:
    x=abs(a-b)
    y.append(x)
print (y)
```

**Output**

```
[6, -8]
```

Comment: Needs to take the biggest of the numbers in the tuple and subtract it by the other.

Comment: There you go, i added the abs() function. It will give you the answer you needed.