# How to create list of differences between tuple values from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have a list of tuples.  Each tuple contains two integers.  I want to create a list of differences between the two integers in each tuple.  Is there a simple way of doing this?

So for example if I have the list:

```
[ (1,2),(3,5),(6,9),(10,15)]
```

The result should be:

```
[1,2,3,5]
```

I am new to python and although I know I could do something like:

```
diff = []
for tup in x:
    diff.append(tup[1]-tup[0])
```

but it seems to me that in python/numpy there is often a one-liner for this sort of thing.

Comment: Even exact duplicate is [how-can-i-subtract-tuples-in-a-list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962463/how-can-i-subtract-tuples-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

`diff = [t[1] - t[0] for t in lst]` , where `lst` is your initial list.

or like it:

`diff = [y - x for x, y in lst]`

or [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

`diff = list(map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], lst))`

If you are using numpy:

```
npl = np.array([(1,2),(3,5),(6,9),(10,15)])
diff = npl[:,1] - npl[:,0]
```

> `array([1, 2, 3, 5])`

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: You can also unpack the tuple directly from the iterator in the list comprehension: `[y - x for x, y in lst]`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!